Displaying a Container with Scroll/Swipe like Whatsapp's LockedChats
I want to Have a Search Bar on top of the chat list but that search bar should appear only when user swipes/scrolls downward and then again hides when scrolls upwards the same behaviar we see for LockedChats option in flutter. The main issue comes when list of chats is not long enough to be scrolled then how can we get the scroll events and hide or show the search Bar. Here is some sample code that works when list is long enough to be scrolled but dont work when list is not scrollable how can I handle that in that case.
class YourWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _YourWidgetState createState() => _YourWidgetState();
}

class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
  bool showSliverToBoxAdapter = false;
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.removeListener(_scrollListener);
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.offset >= 50 && !showSliverToBoxAdapter) {
      setState(() {
        showSliverToBoxAdapter = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: LazyLoadScrollView(
        isLoading: controller.isLoading,
        scrollOffset: 50,
        onEndOfPage: () {},
        child: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: () async {},
          child: CustomScrollView(
            cacheExtent: 2000,
            controller: _scrollController,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            slivers: [
              if (showSliverToBoxAdapter)
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(width: 12),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(243, 242, 248, 1),
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                              height: 34,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4, right: 8),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 17),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 0.4,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                      height: 70,
                      width: 300,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    );
                  },
                  childCount: 17,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


